# What is the origin of イレーザー?

Tags: loanwords

There is a word `イレーザー`, which means 'eraser'. I suspect this comes from the English word `eraser`. But the "s" sound in `eraser` is not voiced in American English, and a closer approximation in kana will be `イレーサー`. How did it become voiced as `イレーザー`?

Edit: After fefe's answer, it turned out I was wrong in writing that "s" is not voiced in English. It turned out to be true for American English.

Comment: It can be voiced according to [thefreedictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/eraser)

Comment: According to some paper dictionary I have, it is a British/American difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/eraser), the 's' is voiced in British English, and unvoiced in American English.

So イレーザー may come from the British reading.